Adding conditional variable in gekko leads to no solution
I'm using gekko to optimize a certain function. When I use a dummy objective function like m.Obj(0) just to test for feasibility, the solver is able to find a feasible solution. However, when I add in my main objective function (commented out below), the solver fails to find a solution. Here's is some fully functioning test code below:
# ## Imports
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

## Set fixed variabls

h_matrix = np.array(
        [
        [119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4],
        [119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4],
        [119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4]
        ]
    )

z_matrix = np.array(
        [
        [383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49],
        [383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49],
        [383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49]
        ]
    )

w = np.array([47.93, 66.37])
h = np.array([12.10, 8.6])
t = np.array([104, 48])


## Reshape the matrices to make calulations easier
h_matrix_reshaped = h_matrix.reshape(30,1)
z_matrix_reshaped = z_matrix.reshape(30,1)


# ## Initialize
# Initialize the model

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

## Fixed variables
h_constants = [m.Param(value=h_matrix_reshaped[i][0]) for i in range(30)]
z_constants = [m.Param(value=z_matrix_reshaped[i][0]) for i in range(30)]

w_base = [m.Param(value=w[i]) for i in range(w.shape[0])]
h_base = [m.Param(value=h[i]) for i in range(h.shape[0])]
t_base = [m.Param(value=t[i]) for i in range(t.shape[0])]

h_cm = m.Param(value=220)
ho_cm = m.Param(value=14.4)
w_kg = m.Param(value=21.2)
s_constraint = m.Param(value=40)

# ### Set up x var (main integer variable)
## Initialize x array

x = np.empty((30, t.shape[0]), dtype=object)
for i in range(30):
    for j in range(t.shape[0]):
        x[i][j] = m.Var(value=0, lb=0, integer=True)
        

# ### Set up Constraints

## Total constraint
for j in range(len(t_base)):
    t_contraints = sum(x[i][j] for i in range(30))
    m.Equation(t_contraints == t_base[j])


## Weight contraints
for i in range(30):
    w_constraints = sum(x[i][j]*w_base[j] for j in range(len(w_base))) + w_kg
    m.Equation(w_constraints <= z_constants[i])

## Height constraints
for i in range(30):
    h_constraints = sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) + ho_cm
    m.Equation(h_constraints <= h_cm)


## Neighbor constraints
for i in range(9):
    # set neighbor constraints horizontally over first row
    neighbor_constraints_1 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+1][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i+1]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_1 <= s_constraint)
    
for i in range(10,19):  
    # set neighbor constraints horizontally over second row
    neighbor_constraints_2 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+1][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i+1]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_2 <= s_constraint)
    
for i in range(20,29):  
    # set neighbor constraints horizontally over second row
    neighbor_constraints_3 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+1][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i+1]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_3 <= s_constraint)
    
for i in range(10):
    # set neighbor constrainst vertically A with B 
    neighbor_constraints_4 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+10][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i+10]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_4 <= s_constraint)

for i in range(10,20):
    # set neighbor constrainst vertically B with C
    neighbor_constraints_5 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+10][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i+10]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_5 <= s_constraint)
    



# ### Mix Score section below ##################

## Create a binary variable/array b that identifies if x[i][j] is non-zero or not
## We will use the count of these b[i][j] values in our objective function

## Constraint to set b[i][k] = 1 if x[i][k] > 0, and 0 otherwise
## Use if3 to set b directly based on x values
b = np.empty((30, len(t_base)), dtype=object)
epsilon = 1e-2  # Small margin allows floating-point considerations

for i in range(30):
    for j in range(len(t_base)):
        b[i][j] = m.if3(x[i][j] - epsilon, 0, 1)

# # Calculation of count(i) for each row
counts = [m.Intermediate(m.sum(b[i])) for i in range(30)]

# # x_sums for sum of each row in x
x_sums = [m.Intermediate(m.sum(x[i])) for i in range(30)]

### Mix Score section above #############################

# ## Run Solver ##

## Set a dummy objective just to identify solutions that are feasible
m.Obj(0)

# Define the main objective function
# mix_score = [counts[i] / m.max2(x_sums[i], 1e-3) for i in range(30)]
# m.Obj(m.sum(mix_score))  


# Set the solver options
m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT solver for non-linear programs

# Increase max iterations because we don't care much about time
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-4',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 50000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 40000']


## Solve
m.solve(disp=True)

In the Mix score section, you'll see where I include conditional variables defined as the b[i][j] that are 1 or 0 depending on the value of x[i][j] (1 if x[i][j] is non-zero, and 0 otherwise). I would like to apply this binary variable to a count function I'm using in the objective function that is commented out
# diversity_score = [counts[i] / m.max2(x_sums[i], 1e-3) for i in range(30)]
# m.Obj(m.sum(diversity_score))
I'm surprised when I implement the objective function
m.Obj(m.sum(diversity_score))
The solver fails to find a solution, in spite of the fact that I know it can identify at least one feasible solution (from running m.Obj(0)). I would think the solver should at least return a value for the objective function for the feasible x[i][j] found when using m.Obj(0) but it doesn't. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Try using m.max3() with the binary switch function instead of m.max2() that is the MPCC version of the switch function. More information on the continuous gradient-based switch functions are in the Engineering Optimization online course.
# Define the main objective function
mix_score = [counts[i] / m.max3(x_sums[i], 1e-3) for i in range(30)]
m.Obj(m.sum(mix_score))

Making the change to m.max3() produces a successful solution.
--Integer Solution:   7.34E+00 Lowest Leaf:   7.33E+00 Gap:   2.49E-04
Iter:  3225 I:  0 Tm:      0.01 NLPi:    5 Dpth:   98 Lvs: 1026 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3226 I: -1 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    5 Dpth:  100 Lvs: 1025 Obj:  7.33E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3227 I: -1 Tm:      0.03 NLPi:    5 Dpth:  100 Lvs: 1024 Obj:  7.33E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3228 I: -1 Tm:      0.01 NLPi:    2 Dpth:  100 Lvs: 1023 Obj:  7.33E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3229 I: -1 Tm:      0.03 NLPi:    5 Dpth:  103 Lvs: 1022 Obj:  7.33E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3230 I:  0 Tm:      0.03 NLPi:    7 Dpth:  103 Lvs: 1021 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3231 I:  0 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    5 Dpth:  103 Lvs: 1020 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3232 I: -1 Tm:      0.04 NLPi:    7 Dpth:   87 Lvs: 1019 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3233 I:  0 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    5 Dpth:   87 Lvs: 1021 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3234 I:  0 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    6 Dpth:   87 Lvs: 1020 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3235 I: -1 Tm:      0.03 NLPi:    7 Dpth:   94 Lvs: 1019 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3236 I: -1 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    4 Dpth:   94 Lvs: 1018 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3237 I:  0 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    5 Dpth:   94 Lvs: 1017 Obj:  7.35E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3238 I: -1 Tm:      0.05 NLPi:    9 Dpth:   88 Lvs: 1016 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3239 I:  0 Tm:      0.03 NLPi:    5 Dpth:   88 Lvs: 1015 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
Iter:  3240 I:  0 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    5 Dpth:   88 Lvs: 1014 Obj:  7.34E+00 Gap:  2.49E-04
 No additional trial points, returning the best integer solution
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    110.606499999994      sec
 Objective      :    7.33571428571429     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

Here is the complete script:
# ## Imports
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

## Set fixed variabls

h_matrix = np.array(
        [
        [119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4],
        [119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4],
        [119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4, 111.4]
        ]
    )

z_matrix = np.array(
        [
        [383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49],
        [383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49],
        [383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 383.91, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49, 254.49]
        ]
    )

w = np.array([47.93, 66.37])
h = np.array([12.10, 8.6])
t = np.array([104, 48])


## Reshape the matrices to make calulations easier
h_matrix_reshaped = h_matrix.reshape(30,1)
z_matrix_reshaped = z_matrix.reshape(30,1)


# ## Initialize
# Initialize the model

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

## Fixed variables
h_constants = [m.Param(value=h_matrix_reshaped[i][0]) for i in range(30)]
z_constants = [m.Param(value=z_matrix_reshaped[i][0]) for i in range(30)]

w_base = [m.Param(value=w[i]) for i in range(w.shape[0])]
h_base = [m.Param(value=h[i]) for i in range(h.shape[0])]
t_base = [m.Param(value=t[i]) for i in range(t.shape[0])]

h_cm = m.Param(value=220)
ho_cm = m.Param(value=14.4)
w_kg = m.Param(value=21.2)
s_constraint = m.Param(value=40)

# ### Set up x var (main integer variable)
## Initialize x array

x = np.empty((30, t.shape[0]), dtype=object)
for i in range(30):
    for j in range(t.shape[0]):
        x[i][j] = m.Var(value=0, lb=0, integer=True)
        

# ### Set up Constraints

## Total constraint
for j in range(len(t_base)):
    t_contraints = sum(x[i][j] for i in range(30))
    m.Equation(t_contraints == t_base[j])


## Weight contraints
for i in range(30):
    w_constraints = sum(x[i][j]*w_base[j] for j in range(len(w_base))) + w_kg
    m.Equation(w_constraints <= z_constants[i])

## Height constraints
for i in range(30):
    h_constraints = sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) + ho_cm
    m.Equation(h_constraints <= h_cm)


## Neighbor constraints
for i in range(9):
    # set neighbor constraints horizontally over first row
    neighbor_constraints_1 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+1][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i+1]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_1 <= s_constraint)
    
for i in range(10,19):  
    # set neighbor constraints horizontally over second row
    neighbor_constraints_2 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+1][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i+1]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_2 <= s_constraint)
    
for i in range(20,29):  
    # set neighbor constraints horizontally over second row
    neighbor_constraints_3 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+1][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i+1]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_3 <= s_constraint)
    
for i in range(10):
    # set neighbor constrainst vertically A with B 
    neighbor_constraints_4 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+10][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i+10]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_4 <= s_constraint)

for i in range(10,20):
    # set neighbor constrainst vertically B with C
    neighbor_constraints_5 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+10][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i+10]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_5 <= s_constraint)
    



# ### Mix Score section below ##################

## Create a binary variable/array b that identifies if x[i][j] is non-zero or not
## We will use the count of these b[i][j] values in our objective function

## Constraint to set b[i][k] = 1 if x[i][k] > 0, and 0 otherwise
## Use if3 to set b directly based on x values
b = np.empty((30, len(t_base)), dtype=object)
epsilon = 1e-2  # Small margin allows floating-point considerations

for i in range(30):
    for j in range(len(t_base)):
        b[i][j] = m.if3(x[i][j] - epsilon, 0, 1)

# # Calculation of count(i) for each row
counts = [m.Intermediate(m.sum(b[i])) for i in range(30)]

# # x_sums for sum of each row in x
x_sums = [m.Intermediate(m.sum(x[i])) for i in range(30)]

### Mix Score section above #############################

# ## Run Solver ##

## Set a dummy objective just to identify solutions that are feasible
#m.Obj(0)

# Define the main objective function
mix_score = [counts[i] / m.max3(x_sums[i], 1e-3) for i in range(30)]
m.Obj(m.sum(mix_score))

# Set the solver options
m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT solver for non-linear programs

# Increase max iterations because we don't care much about time
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-4',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 50000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 40000']

## Solve
m.solve(disp=True)

There are APOPT solver tuning options such as minlp_branch_method 1 and minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2 that have the potential to speed-up the solution if you are okay with an objective of 9.56 (18.5 sec) versus 7.33 (110.6 sec) on a MacBook Pro M1 Processor.
Iter:   615 I:  0 Tm:      0.01 NLPi:    4 Dpth:  168 Lvs:  147 Obj:  9.53E+00 Gap:       NaN
Iter:   616 I: -1 Tm:      0.01 NLPi:    3 Dpth:  169 Lvs:  146 Obj:  9.53E+00 Gap:       NaN
Iter:   617 I: -1 Tm:      0.01 NLPi:    2 Dpth:  169 Lvs:  145 Obj:  9.53E+00 Gap:       NaN
Iter:   618 I:  0 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    4 Dpth:  169 Lvs:  147 Obj:  9.55E+00 Gap:       NaN
Iter:   619 I: -1 Tm:      0.01 NLPi:    3 Dpth:  170 Lvs:  146 Obj:  9.55E+00 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   9.56E+00 Lowest Leaf:   8.05E+00 Gap:   1.72E-01
Iter:   620 I:  0 Tm:      0.01 NLPi:    4 Dpth:  170 Lvs:  145 Obj:  9.56E+00 Gap:  1.72E-01
 Warning: best integer solution returned after maximum MINLP iterations
 Adjust minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol          100  in apopt.opt to change limit
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    18.4835999999777      sec
 Objective      :    9.56190468809906     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

Relax Neighbor Constraints
There is a follow-up question about inability to obtain a feasible solution when the Neighbor Constraints are removed. If the problem completes successfully with a constraint, but not without the constraint then the constraint likely helps bound the problem so that it narrows the feasibility space to help find the optimal solution. There may be a successful solution without the constraint or it possibly makes the problem unbounded (no solution). One way to determine the effect of the constraint is to add a slack variable (e.g. slk) and successively increase slk with subsequent solves to determine the result.
slk = m.Param(0)

## Neighbor constraints
for i in range(9):
    # set neighbor constraints horizontally over first row
    neighbor_constraints_1 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+1][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i+1]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_1 <= s_constraint + slk)
    
for i in range(10,19):  
    # set neighbor constraints horizontally over second row
    neighbor_constraints_2 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+1][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i+1]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_2 <= s_constraint + slk)
    
for i in range(20,29):  
    # set neighbor constraints horizontally over second row
    neighbor_constraints_3 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+1][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                               h_constants[i+1]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_3 <= s_constraint + slk)
    
for i in range(10):
    # set neighbor constrainst vertically A with B 
    neighbor_constraints_4 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+10][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i+10]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_4 <= s_constraint + slk)

for i in range(10,20):
    # set neighbor constrainst vertically B with C
    neighbor_constraints_5 = m.abs3((sum(x[i][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i]) - (sum(x[i+10][j]*h_base[j] for j in range(len(h_base))) +
                                h_constants[i+10]))
    m.Equation(neighbor_constraints_5 <= s_constraint + slk)

The solve command can be called multiple times with a different value for slk.
## Solve
for i in [0,1,5,50,500,5000]:
    slk.value = i
    m.solve(disp=True)


Worked like a charm, John.. Thanks a million!

Thanks for the additional comment regarding the constraints and the additional slack variable, John.
